# How to search near by locations using latitudes and longitudes from Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-places

I'm not sure how to put this question. My web app has number of user profiles with latitudes and longitudes of each user's location. They are obtained by Google maps.

I need to put a query to **Google maps API** to search one user's location against all other users' locations to find out user's near by people in a selected region.

Could anyone please give me a hint on how to achieve this using Google maps or any other mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. This might be an ideal solution [Click Here](http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php)

**Edit:**
An example as per the given solution above

```
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";
```